# apache-spark GPU installation with RAPIDS

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, gpu, rapids

sorry i'm new to the world spark,
I should install it on a cluster that has a node with 2 nvidia AMPERE GPUs, I find written in this [NVIDIA link](https://nvidia.github.io/spark-rapids/docs/get-started/getting-started-on-prem.html) in the Install Spark paragraph that: "note that only scala version 2.12 is currently supported by the accelerator."

I would like to install latest version of Spark 3.3 which supports from what I see scale 2.13, however I will only work with python. What I don't understand is that if this NVIDIA plugin only supports scale 2.12 but all other versions of other programming languages do and therefore I have no problem running python on GPUs, I have to use scale and version 2.12 only. to be able to work with GPUs and therefore python is not possible to use it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This question was addressed here: https://github.com/NVIDIA/spark-rapids/discussions/6739 with a script to allow you to use both GPUs is with a single node standalone cluster, found here: https://github.com/NVIDIA/spark-rapids/discussions/6739#discussioncomment-3830105